# How to solve a problem to match the expected output in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

The meal before tax and tip is 12.00, the tax percentage of the meal is 20% and the tip of the meal is 8%.
You need the use Scanner class to receive input from the user.

```
12.00
20
8
```

The expected output is:

```
15
```

I tried different ways especially with the code below but I'm getting different result. I can't get 15 as the expected out put.

```
enter public class MealSolution {

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    
       System.out.print("Enter cost of meal: ");
       double meal_cost = scanner.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the tip percent: ");
       int tip_percent = scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter tax of meal: ");
       int tax_percent = scanner.nextInt();

       double  tip = meal_cost * tip_percent/100;
       double  tax = meal_cost * tax_percent/100;
       double  cost = meal_cost + tip + tax;
       long total_cost = Math.round(cost);
       System.out.println(total_cost);
    
       scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `double  tax = (meal_cost * (tax_percent)/100);` <- what are the brackets around `(tax_percent)` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I get 15.554 as the cost. I use (cost * 1.2) + (cost * 1.08).

Comment: For your divisions, divide by 100.0. As it is, your using integer division.

Comment: You also don't need to use parentheses around a single variable.

Comment: @NomadMaker, that is a good point, but because `meal_cost` is a double, the entire expression is, in fact, resolved through floating-point division (and yes, i checked). Using 100.0 would be more robust and avoid accidentally breaking the code on future changes, but as it is, it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total cost, take the meal cost and *add* the tip and the tax.

```
   double  cost = meal_cost + tip + tax;
```

Comment: thanks for correction. I change multiplication with addition operators but I'm getting different result still.

Comment: Now you are adding tip, tip again, and tax. You need to add cost of meal, tip, and tax. Try working this out in a calculator or on a piece of paper.